# Undo svn up in non-recursive checked out directory

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a checked out directory `a`, with a subdirectory `b`:

```
svn co --non-recursive a
cd a
svn up b/
```

after some work has been done I'd like to get rid of `b` in order to save disk space. In other words, I'd like to get back to the initial state when I first ran `svn co --non-recursive a`.

If I just `rm -rf b` I get:

```
svn st
!    b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `svn update --set-depth exclude b` instead of just deleting the directory. See the [svn update](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) entry in the svn book.